# JSON ChangeProcessor example

Tags: javers

Is there any example of JSON ChangeProcessor?
In order to have a changelog into JSON format, e.g. to provide data through an API or to a web interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to serialize `Diff` or `Snapshot` objects produced by Javers, it can be done by internal `JsonConverter`:

```
        Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build()
        Diff diff = javers.compare(new Item(1234), new Item(5678))
        String json = javers.getJsonConverter().toJson(diff)
```

Comment: Thank this is a very interesting tip!
But I was looking also for something to make the changelog JSON-like.

Comment: What do you mean by chanlog? Diff is a list of changes so it's a kind of changelog.

Comment: I mean this https://javers.org/documentation/repository-examples/#change-log.
More specifically a kind of JSON ChangeProcessor

Comment: well, I don't have such example but this task (change text to JSON) looks easy, or am I missing something?

Comment: I found that the task of creating an object that represents the commit and all changes occurred is not so trivial. Extending AbstractTextChangeLog allows to code in JSON single data entities (like commit, propertyChange, referenceChange, etc.), but putting all this data in a logical history that puts all of them together, is not so simple